# How to apply opacity to a parent wihout affecting the child?

Tags: css

I have this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/funguy/jKfeQ/

Dont be confused, its something here, but slighly visible. I want to apply the opacity only to the .postmorewrapper1, but not to the .read-more1 .

Any advices on how I can reach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't, you'll need to make them siblings and position them to emulate parent/child.

Answer (score 0):

As said by AlienWebguy, you can't do it with a CSS property like Opacity without affecting the children.

If you really need to change the opacity of a parent without affecting it's children, the best *cheat* would be to swap the background-image of the parent to a png transparent, this way the children won't be affected and the opacity of the parent would seem changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `opacity` property applies to all child elements. An alternative would be to instead use `rgba` when specifying the background colour to `.postmorewrapper1`, as opposed to a hex value. So instead of this:

```
background: #FCFCFC;
opacity: 0.4;
```

Try this:

```
background: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.4)
```

One thing to bear in mind with this technique though is that IE versions 8 and below don't support rgba (it was added in v9). There are a couple of options to get around this:

1. Use an IE filter (which can have an impact on performance if overused)
2. Use a semi-transparent PNG image for IE versions 8 and under (which is less maintainable)

The CSS for option 1 would be:

```
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66FCFCFC,endColorstr=#66FCFCFC)"; /* IE8 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66FCFCFC,endColorstr=#66FCFCFC);   /* IE6 & 7 */
zoom: 1;
```

You'd put that in your IE stylesheet if you have one.